# Is there a reason I would need both ng-annotate-loader and ng-annotate-webpack-plugin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, package.json, ng-annotate

I recently inherited a project written in AngularJS v1.6.x and using Webpack v3.x.x. Upon inspecting the package.json, I noticed that both ng-annotate-loader and ng-annotate-webpack-plugin are listed within the devDependencies section. While ng-annoate-loader runs ng-annotate annotates on the application and generates a sourcemap and ng-annotate-webpack-plugin runs ng-annotate on bundles, I don't see a reason to use both, nor have I been able to find any search results mentioning use both or one vs the other. It seems like I can remove one of those devDependencies.

Do I need to use both, or can I get rid of one the aforementioned devDependencies?

If I can get rid of one, which one should I remove?